Opencart: error updating PayPal Standard to PayPal Commerce Platform
Opencart: I am trying to update PayPal Standard to PayPal Commerce Platform. I  get the following error uploading the extension:
PHP Warning: ftp_chdir(): Can’t change directory to public_html/anaheimgear: No such file or directory in 
/home/customer/www/anaheimgear.com/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-admin_controller_extension_installer.php on line 299

In system information my root path is /home/u267-iwmagmnuqógd/www/anaheimgear.com/public_html
I am hosting on SiteGround.
Any ideas? Truly stuck.
I have looked at the code in question, but do not see how to change unless I comment it out...

I actually changed the code in the admin_controller_extension_installer.php and was able to upload the extension.
